# Yii & Sphinx : searchd error: client version is higher than daemon version (client is v.1.23, daemon is v.1.22)

Tags: php, yii, sphinx

I have a project under Yii MVC, I added a Sphinx component, found here [Yii Sphinx component](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dgsphinxsearch/) and after configurations, I got this error:

> DGSphinxSearchException searchd error: client version is higher than
>   daemon version (client is v.1.23, daemon is v.1.22)

What's with this error? What should I understand from it and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Run `searchd --help` to get the actual sphinxd server version
2. Download that version from http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/archive/
3. Replace the sphinxapi.php in the Yii component